# Checkbox in tabulator row

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabulator

I'm having problems trying to insert a checkbox in tabulator.

I don't know if you know what tabulator is but is a library to create tables with javascript and jquery.

In the tabulator documentation it says that the column has to be declared like this to insert the checkbox:

```js
{title:"Example", field:"example", editor:"tick"}
```

But when I do it at first the checkbox is not visible, I have to pass over it with de mouse to make it visible and when I click on it, it changes from a checkbox to a "true".

I don't know what I'm doing wrong bc the tabulator documentation doesn't say anything more. Do any of you know how to solve it?

Comment: you mean you want to add a checkbox to select a row?

Comment: i solved it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have defined a "tick" editor, editors are only visible when the cell has focus.

If you want the column to always display a tick, then you should be using the ***tickCross*** formatter

```js
_{title:"Example", field:"example", editor:"tickCross"}_
```